# Packaging and AIR app for iOS causes version number discrepancies

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I'm packaging an iOS app built in Adobe AIR, and have noticed some odd behaviour relating to version numbers.

When I set the versionNumber in the app descriptor and build it, the resulting .ipa file has a different short version number.

Steps to demonstrate: 
I set the app version number in my app descriptor to be 2.0.001, like so:
`<versionNumber>2.0.001</versionNumber>`

If I then compile the app, break open the resulting .ipa and check info.plist, I see the "Bundle versions string, short" as the correct value: **2.0.001**

However, I see the Bundle Version as **2.0.99**

This other value is definitely not set anywhere manually, this is a clean project for testing this out.

My question then, is: why would **2.0.001** become **2.0.99** when building? What's actually happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug at Adobe's side. Frustrating.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3598688

Answer (score 1):

Set xml file property readOnly. Flash can't change readOnly xml files.

Comment: Can you a clarify a little on this?

Comment: Right click to xml file, then click Properties. Then check Read-only box. Now start packaging.